# Configurable Product Price is 0 in API Response

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Dears, Why Configurable products price is always displayed as `0` in rest API response like (sku related to magento 2 sample data):

http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/MH01

Although it is displayed as a real price `52.00$` in the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because configurable product don't have price in Magento 2 by self and price on frontend is minimal price of linked simple products

Comment: Thanks .. What is the best practice to solve this slot? I don't need to display 0 prices in my mobile app !

Comment: Currently, Magento does not provide this API by self. You can implement it by self

Comment: Thanks, Kindly could you answer this question ?